# How to set actions for Push notification alert view in iOS

Tags: iphone, action, push-notification, uialertview

In my application I have implemented the Push notification feature and I am getting the notifications. I used the following code in the appDelegate file.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [userInfo objectForKey:key];
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array valueForKey:@"alert"]];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"iPhoneApp" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }    
}
```

I want to perform actions on the OK button click event of the Push notification alert (when the app is running). I have three view controllers in this app. So in which class should I add the code

`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`?

Comment: The .m file in which u want to show the `UIAlertView` in that file u can add the delegate method of `UIAlertView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same class you set as the `delegate` of that particular UIAlertView. In your current case, the `AppDelegate` is the receiver of the `-clickedButtonAtIndex:`.

If you would like to receive the click events in one of the 3 controllers you have. You must set that particular controller as the delegate to your `UIAlertView`:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"iPhoneApp" message:message delegate:myViewController cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

As you see I assigned `myViewController` as the delegate. `myViewController` should conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol and implement the `-clickedButtonAtIndex:` method. Now once you select one of the button's you will get the call in `myViewController`.